# Does webp support grayscale colorspace?

Tags: grayscale, color-space, image-conversion, webp

I see official cwebp document have no option to specify target colorspace
https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp

because I wish using grayscale color space could save some space for text image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Specification for WebP Lossless Bitstream](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/webp_lossless_bitstream_specification) and the [VP8 Data Format and Decoding Guide](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6386#section-9.2), WebP only deals with (A)RGB.

Checkout the libwebp [decode](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/main/src/webp/decode.h) and [encode](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/main/src/webp/encode.h) APIs.