# Save and load a Grayscale WebP image in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save and load a grayscale image in PIL:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
o = np.random.rand(100,100)*255
o = o.astype('uint8')
im = Image.fromarray((o))
im.save('test.webp', lossless=True)
im = Image.open(r"test.webp")
a = np.asarray(im)
a.shape
```

`a.shape` outputs `(100, 100, 3)`, apparently it is saved as a RGB image. This doesn't happen if I save the image as PNG, it loads as `(100,100,1)`. What to do?

Comment: It looks like it may not be an option, not because of PIL but because of WebP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51006981/5987

Comment: Right.  WebP only supports RGBA.  Stick with PNG.